# Get response from a HTTP request in ionic

Tags: php, ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I read a response from an http request in ionic? I am creating a login page in ionic and I am trying to get the response from the php code which is in json object. The response from the backend was returned by I couldn't grab it in ionic.

**.ts code**

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:83/api/v2/signin.php", JSON.stringify(this.credentials))
        .subscribe(data => {
          
          this.data = data;
          console.log(this.data);

          if(data.response=="success"){
            let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'Login was successfully',
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'top',
              cssClass: 'dark-trans',
              closeButtonText: 'OK',
              showCloseButton: true
            });
            toast.present();
           
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);           
            this.storage.set("session",response);
            this.global.session=response;
          }else{
            this.global.loginState="login";
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              
              subTitle: data.response,
              buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
          }
```

When login fails, the following is been displayed in the console

```
Response {_body: "{"response":"Invalid login details entered"}"
```

**On success** I have the following

```
 Object { _body: "{\"response\":\"success\",
   \"data\":{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"Eli James\",
   \"email\":\"eli_james@gmail.com\"}}",
  status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK",
```

My php code is like this:

```
         if($row['email']==$email AND 
                 $row['status']=='1'){
       
                       $response=array(
                        "response"=>"success",
                        "data"=>array(
                            "id"=>$row['id'],
                            "name"=>$row['name'],                     
                            "email"=>$row['email']

                            )

                        );          
                      }else{
                    $response=array("response"=>"Invalid login details entered");
                     }
                   echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting response body as a `string` from the backend. You will have to parse the body as a JSON and then use it.

Just change the line from `this.data = data;` to `this.data = JSON.parse(data)`.

Or `this.data = JSON.parse(data._data);`

Answer (score 0):

Tell HttpClient that you want the full response with the observe option of the post() method:

this.http.post("http://localhost:83/api/v2/signin.php", JSON.stringify(this.credentials), {observe: 'response')
.subscribe(fullResponse => {
.......

Now httpClient returns an Observable of type HttpResponse rather than just the JSON data contained in the body.